# Inserting multiple values into table with anorm

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

I want to insert multiple values into a table from a SQL query in Anorm. In the following snippet, is there a way to bind a list of usernames as values instead of just one username?

```
SQL("insert into users (username) " +
      "values ({username})").on(
      'username -> username,
    ).executeUpdate()
```

As an alternative, I can create a concatenated string from my inputs, but that's prone to SQL injection and isn't quite as clean.

Answer (score 5):

A possible way to insert multiple values at once, using Anorm:

```
var fields: List[String] = Nil
var values: List[(String,ParameterValue[_])] = Nil

for ((username,i) <- usernames.zipWithIndex) {
  fields ::= "({username%s})".format(i)
  values ::= ("username" + i, username)
}

SQL("INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES %s".format(fields.mkString(",")))
  .on(values: _*)
  .executeUpdate()
```

Comment: I guess the version of anorm I'm using has changed a little; I needed to do `var values: List[NamedParameter] = Nil` as `ParameterValue` doesn't take type parameters and `.on(values: _*)` couldn't seem to find an implicit conversion from the list of tuples. Given that, it works a treat, and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: There is new support for this in 2.6.X
https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAnorm#Batch-update

Answer (score 0):

You're wanting to repeat the insert command for all of the values?

How about wrapping it in a foreach:

```
usernames.foreach(username =>
  SQL("insert into users (username) " +
    "values ({username})").on(
    'username -> username,
  ).executeUpdate())
```

Or something of that sort.

Anorm is a relatively simple library--check out the code here:
https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/framework/src/anorm/src/main/scala/anorm

Comment: He want to to a multiple insert in one request (for optimization I suppose), like `insert into users(username) VALUES 'julien', 'clara', 'paul')`

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that was a possibility. Anorm doesn't know that you're performing an insert, so it doesn't know how to do that sort of thing. It's not that sophisticated.

Comment: That's right, I'm looking for a way to insert multiple values at once, like @JulienLafont suggested. There doesn't seem to be anything like what I need, so I'll create the sql query string myself.

Comment: Check out David Ross' reply here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/meYkd-KKQRE/rdVmOJ9TO78J ... perhaps with some rebuilding you can this for the multiple inserts as well? (It's over my head.)