# Inserting multiple values and fields into table with anorm

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, anorm

I found this answer that solves to one field -> [Inserting multiple values into table with anorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675862/inserting-multiple-values-into-table-with-anorm)

```
   var fields: List[String] = Nil
var values: List[(String,ParameterValue[_])] = Nil

for ((username,i) <- usernames.zipWithIndex) {
  fields ::= "({username%s})".format(i)
  values ::= ("username" + i, username)
}

SQL("INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES %s".format(fields.mkString(",")))
  .on(values: _*)
  .executeUpdate()
```

How can I pass  more fields, like username, address, phonenumber, etc?

I tried ...

```
 def create(names: List[(String,ParameterValue[_])] ,addresses :List[(String,ParameterValue[_])]){

   var fields: List[String] = Nil;

   for((a,i) <- names.zipWithIndex){
      fields ::= "({name%s},{address%s})".format(i)
   }
           DB.withConnection { implicit c =>

           SQL("insert into table (name,address) values  %s".format(fields.mkString(",")))
          .on(names: _*, addresses: _*)
          .executeUpdate()
           }
 }
```

I get the following error:
" no "_ *" annotation allowed here"

If I could use one single list to all parameters it'll even better.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to perform a batch insert. Here's an adaptation taken from the docs:

```
import anorm.BatchSql

val batch = BatchSql(
  "INSERT INTO table (name, address) VALUES({username}, {address})", 
  Seq(names, addresses)
)

val res: Array[Int] = batch.execute() // array of update count
```

Comment: names and adresses in your code are my Lists received as parameters?
Is it possible to use a single list, in this way you answer?

Comment: I'm getting the following error: "NoSuchElementException: key not found : address"